# Service worker getting unregistered unexpectedly

Tags: workbox

We have deployed a web app for 1million+ users, and as per analytics we collected, it looks like service worker is getting unregistered unexpectedly.

We are registering service worker on every page, but after a few seconds its state is going to `redundant`. And it happens when the page is open. We are listening to `statechange` event and we verified that it's not triggered by our app. We doubt some external source is triggering unregistration.

This problem happens in production for a small group of users 1% and we are not able to reproduce this ourselves. And it happening on all browsers.

What are the possibilities of external sources unregistering service worker?